# Change IE7 HTML Tag width

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7

I can't seem to change  width in IE7

http://jsfiddle.net/Mkb9n/1/

You can see that all other browsers (including IE8+) will put the background image INSIDE the 200px, while IE7 will simply ignore the html width rule.

Any solution?

EDIT : Apparently all browsers return approximately the same width on html tag inside the jsfiddle iframe, the problem is the background position in IE7 is relative to html instead of body.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend found the solution:

the trick is to add background-color (any color will do) in your html tag, then add your background-image to your body tag (preferably with a background-color suitable with your background-image)

http://jsfiddle.net/Mkb9n/3/

Answer (score 1):

That's IE7. Try setting it as DIVs background - http://jsfiddle.net/Mkb9n/2/

Answer (score 0):

you can specify fixed offset, assuming you are using the fixed width:

```
background: url("http://mediacdn.disqus.com/uploads/users/967/956/avatar92.jpg?1340672375") 
no-repeat 50px bottom;
```